# How to convert an image to animation?

Tags: image, animation, processing, fractals

I would like to apply some recursive mathematical operation on an arbitrary photo or image, which yield an interesting animation. I mean the first frame is the original picture and then the pixels are transformed in a way which leads to an interesting animation. For example a fractal animation or diffusion as particles or something similar. What approaches should I follow, what softwares to apply?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, and it's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. Stack Overflow is designed more for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. That being said, I'll try to answer in a general sense:

**Step 1:** [Download Processing](https://processing.org/). You've tagged this with the [processing](/questions/tagged/processing) tag, which is for questions about the Processing language. I can't tell whether that was on purpose, but it doesn't matter since Processing happens to be perfect for this task.

**Step 2:** Create a simple sketch that displays a single image, without any effects or animation. You need to break your problem down into smaller steps.

**Step 3:** Create a function that takes a [`PImage`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html) or a [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) and does the image manipulation for a single iteration of your algorithm. There are plenty of useful functions in the reference for manipulating the pixels in an image.

**Step 4:** Start with your initial image, and display that for X frames. Then pass that image into the function you created in step 3, and display the result of that for X frames. Then pass the update image back into your function, and repeat that process as many times as you want.

You could also generate every single frame ahead of time. Completely up to you.

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but those steps are the general outline. Please try something out, and break your problem down into smaller steps. Don't try to tackle your whole goal at one time. Instead, ask yourself: what's the smallest, simplest, easiest thing I know I have to do next?

If you get stuck, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (note: not your whole sketch, just a small example that shows the problem you're stuck on) and a specific question, and we'll go from there. Good luck.